# Define instance method with "macro inherited" in Crystal 0.21.1

Tags: crystal-lang

As I understand it the type declaration works like `kind_of`…

> “So types aren't strictly the type named but rather act like a `is_a?` or `kind_of?`.” https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/4232

So I think that part of this code works.

But when I use a macro to define an instance method on an inherited class the error message complains about the method missing from the wrong object.

```
class Base
  macro inherited
    def name
      "Joe Smith"
    end
  end
end

class Context < Base; end

class Render
  def initialize(@inner_context : Base); end

  def display
    name
  end

  forward_missing_to inner_context

  private property inner_context
end

puts Render.new(Context.new).display
```

And the output is:

```
Error in line 23: instantiating 'Render#display()'

in line 15: instantiating 'name()'

in macro 'forward_missing_to' /usr/lib/crystal/object.cr:1132, line 1:

>  1.     macro method_missing(call)
   2.       inner_context.{{call}}
   3.     end
   4.   

expanding macro
in macro 'method_missing' expanded macro: forward_missing_to:1, line 1:

>  1.       inner_context.name
   2.     

undefined method 'name' for Base (compile-time type is Base+)
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@inner_context` could be of type `Base`, which **doesn't** define a `base` method.

One solution is to mark `Base` as abstract: `abstract class Base`.